# how to fetch data from table comment

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql, comments

i try

> SELECT post_id, created_time FROM stream WHERE source_id=me()

it works well, but once i rewrite it into

> SELECT fromid FROM comment WHERE post_id LIKE '1785406639_%'

it failed......here are the error messages

(i use the default app code to show the result)

> Warning: array_key_exists() expects parameter 2 to be array, integer given in /app/www/utils.php on line 24
>   Warning: array_key_exists() expects parameter 2 to be array, string given in /app/www/utils.php on line 24

how can I do to fetch the fromid from table comment?

Answer (score 3):

will this `SELECT * FROM comment`  return any values ?

Answer (score 0):

FQL is not SQL  For language syntax see: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/